# Link table column values ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making a website dashboard for administrating some values. I want to link a column in a table called Category to another table called Menu, in both tables I have a Category column, and when I display them on my view I want display them category by category. This is how I currently display the Menu table:

```
<section id="pt2">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <table id="dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{int rowCounterMenu = -1;}
            @foreach (var menu in Model.Menu)
            {
                rowCounterMenu++;
                <tr>
                    <form class="dataFormMenu" asp-controller="Administration" asp-action="UpdateMenu" method="post">

                    <th>@menu.Id</th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="nameColumnMenu">@menu.Name</div>

                        <input hidden name="Id" value="@menu.Id" />
                        <input class="editNameColumnMenu" name="Name" placeholder="Name" value="@menu.Name" />

                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="descriptionColumnMenu">@menu.Description</div>
                        <input class="editDescriptionColumnMenu" name="Description" placeholder="Description" value="@menu.Description" />
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="priceColumnMenu">@menu.Price kr</div>
                        <input class="editPriceColumnMenu" name="Price" placeholder="Price" value="@menu.Price" />
                    </th>
                    <th class="manage">
                        <button type="button" class="editButtonMenu" onclick="displayEditMenu(@rowCounterMenu)">Edit</button>
                        <a onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('dataFormMenu')[@rowCounterMenu].submit();" class="saveButtonMenu">Save</a>
                        <p>|</p>
                        <a asp-action="DeleteMenuItem" asp-route-id="@menu.Id">Delete</a>
                    </th>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <form class="dataFormAddMenuItem" asp-controller="Administration" asp-action="CreateMenuItem" method="post">
                <th><input name="Name" placeholder="Name"/></th>
                <th><input name="Description" placeholder="Description" /></th>
                <th><input name="Price" placeholder="Price" /></th>
                <th class="manage">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                </th>
                </form>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</section>
```

In my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();

            var users = await ApplicationDbContext.Users.ToListAsync(); // Theese are other tables I display
            var daily = await ApplicationDbContext.Daily.ToListAsync(); // Theese are other tables I display
            var menu = await ApplicationDbContext.Menu.ToListAsync();

            mymodel.Users = users;
            mymodel.Daily = daily;
            mymodel.Menu = menu;

            return View(mymodel);

            
        }
```

How do I in my View display only the items that has certain "Category" type? Thanks beforehand!

Here is some images of my SQL structure.

[![Menu SQL Structure][1]][1]
[![Category SQL Structure][2]][2]

Best regards Max

Menu SQL Structure
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXXie.png
Category SQL Structure
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCH1n.png

Comment: How is the category type stored?

Comment: I updated the post, but it is just a column in each table

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the perfect way to solve this problem but I fixed it by changing my view to a select with the items to choose by is only from the categories table.